# How do I access contextual properties for a VSTO Add-in?

Tags: outlook, registry, vsto

I'm trying to access pretty much any identifying property of the Add-in "relationship" or "registration" from a VSTO Add-In to Outlook. How do I access that information from within the running assembly?

Since I'm guessing that doesn't really ask my question very well, I'll back up: in order for Outlook or an office application to recognize and load a VSTO add-in, a registry key must be created in one of a few locations. in this location, there is a key named with the add-in "identifier", and this key then has several values including one which directs the Office application to the assembly for the add-in.

That effectively registers the add-in with the office application, and I want to be able to access something distinguishing about that registration - I think ideally the registry key itself.

Edit/ I would like to be able to register the same assembly more than once, but have it know which "registration" it is, so as to know where to look for different settings for each registration. /edit

Is this possible? How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

A VSTO Add-in basically is a common .NET application that registers some Registry keys for Office to be able to identify the installed add-ins and have Office interact with these add-ins.

Here you can find the Registry information that is used by Office to identify the add-ins.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx

If you take a look at the picture in the following page you can discover how the Add-in is recognized and how it is loaded by the Office client applications:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386298.aspx

Comment: I've got it registered and running just fine - I'm looking to add code to the dll that will allow it to identify itself, distinct from other add-ins, possibly through the registry keys that outlook uses, possibly through some of the values like FriendlyName

Comment: Yes, that is what I understood from your question, and the answer is the same. As you are the owner of the add-in you know where you register the addin, so you can also query that same location. Another option would be to add a global function to your addin that returns its own name. The question is somewhat obscure, as it would be like asking you to confirm your own name. You already know who you are and what your name is. Maybe you should explain some more why you need it and what you want to do with it.

Comment: I made an edit to the post a while back that explains I may not know the exact registry key - ideally, I want it to be able to determine its own "registration" registry key - and thus be able to access other values applied to that key - I don't see any way to do it other than possibly through some API for VSTO Add-Ins...(?). It already has the hard coded registry key that is uses to retrieve some additional settings, but I want to be able to register the same assembly and have it act differently depending upon those other settings (different keys) -- please let me know if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

As alternative to the options in my other answer you can look at the following post, and instead of looking at the product version (as was asked for in the original post for that question) you can get the Assembly information to identify what you are looking for:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d35b9b50-e8c0-4df0-b6a1-5a28ec1f00b6/programmatically-obtain-product-version-of-excel-addin-project-with-visual-basic-net?forum=exceldev